# I am trying to run a function in parallel but it is stuck and runs infinitely until I forcefully interrupt the process

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

When I run this function sequentially with a for-loop, it works just fine but doing it in parallel with multiprocessing makes it run continuously without stopping. I have tried both Pool and Process methods but both give the same problem, can't find where I getting it mixed up.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import io

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
from google.colab import files
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

up = files.upload()
data = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(up['heart.csv']))

#### SEQUENTIAL PROGRAM - This part runs smoothly
            
s1 = time.time()
            
def kmeans(n):
  sc = StandardScaler()
  X = sc.fit_transform(pd.get_dummies(data, drop_first = True))
  ss = []
  km = KMeans(n_clusters=n, random_state=1)
  km = km.fit(X)
  ss.append(km.inertia_)
  print(f"Process {n} is executing")

  return ss
            
for i in range(1, 50):
  kmeans(i)
            
s2 = time.time()
            
print(f"took {s2-s1}s to finish")
        
### Using Multiprocessing- Process() - Runs continuously without stopping
        
tic2 = time.time()
        
process_list = []
for i in range(1, 50):
  p =  mp.Process(target= kmeans, args = [i])
  p.start()
  process_list.append(p)
        
for process in process_list:
  process.join()
        
 toc2 = time.time()
        
 print('Done in {:.4f} seconds'.format(toc2-tic2))
    
    ### Using Multiprocessing- Pool() - Runs continuously without stopping
    
 tic1 = time.time()
    
 pool = mp.Pool()
 pool.map(kmeans, range(1,50))
 pool.close()
    
 toc1 = time.time()
    
 print('Done in {:.4f} seconds'.format(toc1-tic1))
```

Comment: Where is *data* defined?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the nonsensical data this minor variation on your code runs perfectly (if you ignore the exceptions arising from the synthetic data)

Perhaps this will help you to see where you've gone wrong.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas as pd
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import numpy as np
import warnings

def kmeans(n):
    data = ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo']
    ss = []
    print(f"Process {n} is executing")
    try:
        sc = StandardScaler()
        X = sc.fit_transform(pd.get_dummies(data, drop_first=True))
        km = KMeans(n_clusters=n, random_state=1)
        km = km.fit(X)
        ss.append(km.inertia_)
    except Exception:
        pass
    print(f"Process {n} is ending")
    return ss


def main():
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(kmeans, list(range(50)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks Olvin. The aim of the code is to get the sum of square values for 49 runs of the kmeans algorithm simultaneously. However, when i try your code for the data i have, it executes just twice instead of 49 times. Also note that i had previously defined all necessary imports and the data as well, it just wasn't captured in the code uploaded.

Comment: This code will undoubtedly run kmeans() 50 times (0-49 inclusive). Can you update the code in your original question to show what you think is only running it twice? It would be good to see the data too

Comment: I have updated my code, however, i mean it executed only twice when I tried your code on my data. I just downloaded a pre-processed dataset from Kaggle to test it.

Comment: When I try your code, it gives the below output and stops:                                                     
                                                                                                                                  
Process 1 is executing
Process 0 is executing
Process 0 is ending
Process 2 is executing

Comment: I really need to see your **exact** code to understand what you've done here. I repeat - the *kmeans()* function **WILL** be run 50 times as a discrete process with the code shown